# Getting NumberFormatException with Hedera Java SDK setup

Tags: java, hedera-hashgraph

I am stuck at one point.
The function call is not able to read data from .env file.

This is the main file:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws HederaReceiptStatusException, TimeoutException, HederaPreCheckStatusException {

        //Grab your Hedera testnet account ID and private key
        AccountId myAccountId = AccountId.fromString(Dotenv.load().get("MY_ACCOUNT_ID"));
        PrivateKey myPrivateKey = PrivateKey.fromString(Dotenv.load().get("MY_PRIVATE_KEY")); 
......
```

This is the `.env` file:

```
MY_ACCOUNT_ID=TESTNET ACCOUNT ID(0.0.1755600)
MY_PRIVATE_KEY=TESNET PRIVATE KEY(302e020100300506032b657004220420c802435424acd5c73733473532551277503ffd4dcccd1042fc657907828708a5)
```

Comment: Could you show the exception you are getting?

Comment: You realize you just pasted your complete _private_ login details onto a public website, right?

Comment: TESTNET and TESNET, typo

Comment: There is nothing here that would throw `NumberFormatException`. The problem must be in `AccountId.fromString()` or `PrivateKey.fromString()`, neither of which you have posted. And don't post private keys ***anywhere,*** let alone on the Internet. You must now re-key your application.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `.env` file to look similar to as follows:

```
MY_ACCOUNT_ID=0.0.1755600
MY_PRIVATE_KEY=302e020100300506032b657004220420a802435424acd5c73733473532551277503ffd4dcccd1042fc659907828708a5
```

[refer docs](https://docs.hedera.com/guides/docs/sdks/client#from-an-account-id-and-private-key)

Comment: And hw do you magically know the correct format for the OP's private applicaton file?

Comment: @OneCricketeer OP initially had `MY_ACCOUNT_ID=TESTNET ACCOUNT ID(0.0.1755600)`. They need to remove the `TESTNET ACCOUNT ID` and its parenthesis to instead be `MY_ACCOUNT_ID=0.0.1755600`.  As the .env is currently used, its telling the Hedera network their account ID is `TESTNET ACCOUNT ID(0.0.1755600)` instead of `0.0.1755600`. The same change must be made for their `MY_PRIVATE_KEY`.

Comment: If you provided a link to Hedera documentation that pointed out the correct format of the values, then the answer seems fine. Otherwise, seems like a guess since you don't know the expected _Numberformat_. More specifically, without seeing the full stacktrace, we cannot know if the two `fromString` methods are supposed to strip out the prefix `TESTNET...(`

Comment: @OneCricketeer sure, makes sense. Here is the documentation, see 'from a .env file' - https://docs.hedera.com/guides/docs/sdks/client

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Please refer java docs for [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)